# How to npm install --save all packages already installed?

Tags: npm

Is there a way I can update package.json from node_modules directory?
Sometimes I forget to use --save flag.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh I know the problem! But I'm afraid there is no native npm solution. Maybe it's possible to build a shell script iterating over the `node_modules` folder and then running some npm command? I'm very interested for an answer, too!

Comment: @ConcurrentHashMap is it possible to use grunt/gulp for this ?

Comment: iterating each node_modules folder will include rudundant packages as well

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I came up with this simple cmd

`` npm install `ls node_modules` --save ``

It's good enough for my case :-)

Comment: In a blank repository if I `npm install --save chalk`, my node_modules folder contains 7 entries (ansi-regex/  ansi-styles/  chalk/  escape-string-regexp/  has-ansi/  strip-ansi/  supports-color/). installing chalk, node-sass and gulp gives 233 packages in the node_modules folder. I am using git bash on windows.

Comment: @goldenratio At the time I was asking(2014), npm would only install the package on top level. All other dependencies of that package would be installed in local node_modules of that package. You can verify that by download node v0.11.14 or so

Comment: Certainly, but for someone stumbling upon this page today, it could be helpful for them to know this will no longer work.

Comment: I just got lots of `npm ERR! registry error parsing json`

Comment: that may have something to do with npm version.